# Determining if ITypeSymbol is Serializable in the Compiler API

Tags: c#, serialization, roslyn

I need to check a `ITypeSymbol` to see if it's serializable. There's no `IsSerializable` property on `ITypeSymbol` or an extension method that I know of in the Compiler API to do this, so here's the best guess I can come up with:

- If `IsValueType` is true, it's serializable
- If the type has the `[SerializableAttribute]` in the return value from `GetAttributes()`, it's serializable
- If it implements the `ISerializable` interface, it's serializable.

Am I missing any other possibilities?

Comment: You have to use the object's GetType() method to know the concrete type.  After which you have a valid Type.IsSerializable.  Odd question btw, smells like I'm missing something.

Comment: @hansPassant I can't use the Reflection API here. This is the Compiler API, and I don't have access to a `Type` from an `ITypeSymbol` (at least none that I'm aware of). That's the issue.

Comment: Hmya, that's not possible of course.  All you can do is hope that at runtime this turns out well.  Runtime exceptions keep programmers honest, just make sure that the final program fails with a good diagnostic and that somebody can take corrective action.

Comment: @HansPassant All I'm looking for is the equivalent of `IsSerializable` from `Type`. I looked up the code in referencesource and that gave some hints. I get your point about checking at runtime, but this is during analysis, so I need some kind of heuristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to duplicate what `Type.IsSerializable` does, you can look at [its reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,796846975110f529). What it does is:

- return `true` if the type has the `[Serializable]` attribute
- return `true` if the type is `Delegate` or `Enum` or inherits from them, i.e. if the the type is a `delegate` or an `enum`
- otherwise return `false`

This means that your special casing for value types and `ISerializable` implementations is not correct.

Comment: I agree with this....but the only problem with this is that the `Int32` type (via a `ITypeSymbol`) will not have the `[Serializable]` attribute in the `GetAttributes()` call. I can't figure out how to determine if the serialization flag is turned on for these types via the Compiler API.

Comment: Basically I figured out a way to get the serializable flag setting via Reflection, so this all works now. Marking this as the answer.